# How to update collision criterion to check for Sprite overlapping, not just touching?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to update my collision definition.

Now it works as follows. When the object `worker` touches the object `fence`, the collision occurs.

However, the collision should occur only when the `worker` image overlaps with the `fence` image about ~40%. In other words, when it gets placed on top.

I do not need any perfect collision detection.

```
import pygame, random
import sys

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (20, 255, 140)
GREY = (210, 210 ,210)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
PURPLE = (255, 0, 255)

SCREENWIDTH=1000
SCREENHEIGHT=578

IMG_BACKGROUND = "background.jpg"
IMG_WORKER_RUNNING = "images/workers/worker_1.png"
IMG_WORKER_IDLE = "images/workers/worker_2.png"
IMG_WORKER_ACCIDENT = "images/workers/accident.png"


class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location, *groups):
        # we set a _layer attribute before adding this sprite to the sprite groups
        # we want the background to be actually in the back
        self._layer = -1
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups)
        # let's resize the background image now and only once
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(image_file).convert(), (SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=location)



class GeoFenceInfluenceZone(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, rect, *groups):
        # we set a _layer attribute before adding this sprite to the sprite groups
        self._layer = 0
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups)
        self.image = pygame.surface.Surface((rect.width, rect.height))
        self.image.fill(GREY)
        self.rect = rect



class GeoFence(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, rect, risk_level, *groups):
        # we set a _layer attribute before adding this sprite to the sprite groups
        self._layer = 1
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups)
        self.image = pygame.surface.Surface((rect.width, rect.height))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = rect
        self.risk_level = risk_level
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 20)
        text = self.font.render(risk_level, 1, (255,0,0), GREEN)
        text_rect = text.get_rect(center=(rect.width/2, rect.height/2))
        self.image.blit(text, text_rect)



class Worker(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # we introduce to possible states: RUNNING and IDLE
    RUNNING = 0
    IDLE = 1
    ACCIDENT = 2
    NUMBER_OF_ACCIDENTS = 0

    def __init__(self, image_running, image_idle, image_accident, location, *groups):

        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 10)

        # each state has it's own image
        self.images = {
            Worker.RUNNING: pygame.transform.scale(get_image(image_running), (45, 45)),
            Worker.IDLE: pygame.transform.scale(get_image(image_idle), (20, 45)),
            Worker.ACCIDENT: pygame.transform.scale(get_image(image_accident), (40, 40))
        }

        # we set a _layer attribute before adding this sprite to the sprite groups
        # we want the workers on top
        self._layer = 2
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups)

        # let's keep track of the state and how long we are in this state already            
        self.state = Worker.IDLE
        self.ticks_in_state = 0

        self.image = self.images[self.state]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=location)

        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
        self.speed = random.randint(1, 3)
        self.set_random_direction()


    def set_random_direction(self):
        # random new direction or standing still
        vec = pygame.math.Vector2(random.randint(-100,100), random.randint(-100,100)) if random.randint(0, 5) > 1 else pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)

        # check the new vector and decide if we are running or fooling around
        length = vec.length()
        speed = sum(abs(int(v)) for v in vec.normalize() * self.speed) if length > 0 else 0

        if (length == 0 or speed == 0) and (self.state != Worker.ACCIDENT):
            new_state = Worker.IDLE
            self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
        elif self.state != Worker.ACCIDENT:
            new_state = Worker.RUNNING
            self.direction = vec.normalize()
        else:
            new_state = Worker.ACCIDENT

        self.ticks_in_state = 0
        self.state = new_state

        # use the right image for the current state
        self.image = self.images[self.state]


    def update(self, screen):
        self.ticks_in_state += 1
        # the longer we are in a certain state, the more likely is we change direction
        if random.randint(0, self.ticks_in_state) > 70:
            self.set_random_direction()

        # now let's multiply our direction with our speed and move the rect
        vec = [int(v) for v in self.direction * self.speed]
        self.rect.move_ip(*vec)

        # if we're going outside the screen, change direction
        if not screen.get_rect().contains(self.rect):
            self.direction = self.direction * -1

        # spritecollide returns a list of all sprites in the group that collide with
        # the given sprite, but if the sprite is in this group itself, we have
        # to ignore a collision with itself
        if any(s for s in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, building_materials, False) if s != self):
            self.direction = self.direction * -1

        if any(s for s in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, machines, False) if s != self):
            self.direction = self.direction * -1

        # Risk handling
        self.handle_risks()

        if any(s for s in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, fences, False) if s != self):
            Worker.NUMBER_OF_ACCIDENTS += 1

        self.rect.clamp_ip(screen.get_rect())


    def handle_risks(self):
        for s in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, fences, False):
            if s != self:
                self.speed = 0
                self.state = Worker.ACCIDENT
                self.image = self.images[self.state]



class BuildingMaterials(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location, *groups):
        # we set a _layer attribute before adding this sprite to the sprite groups
        self._layer = 2
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(image_file).convert_alpha(), (40, 40))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=location)



class Excavator(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location, *groups):
        # we set a _layer attribute before adding this sprite to the sprite groups
        self._layer = 3
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(image_file).convert_alpha(), (170, 170))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=location)



image_cache = {}
def get_image(key):
    if not key in image_cache:
        image_cache[key] = pygame.image.load(key)
    return image_cache[key]


pygame.init()

# currently, one group would be enough
# but if you want to use some collision handling in the future
# it's best to group all sprites into special groups (no pun intended)
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
workers = pygame.sprite.Group()
building_materials = pygame.sprite.Group()
fences = pygame.sprite.Group()
fences_infl_zones = pygame.sprite.Group()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("TEST")

# create multiple workers
for pos in ((30,30), (50, 400), (200, 100), (700, 200)):
    Worker(IMG_WORKER_RUNNING, IMG_WORKER_IDLE, IMG_WORKER_ACCIDENT, pos, all_sprites, workers, building_materials, machines, fences)

# create multiple building material stocks
for pos in ((50,460),(50,500),(100,500),(850,30),(800,30)):
    BuildingMaterials("images/materials/building_blocks{}.png".format(random.randint(1,3)), pos, all_sprites, building_materials)

# create multiple geo-fences
risks = ["H","M","L"]
for rect in (pygame.Rect(510,150,75,52), pygame.Rect(450,250,68,40), pygame.Rect(450,370,68,48),
             pygame.Rect(0,0,20,SCREENHEIGHT),pygame.Rect(0,0,SCREENWIDTH,20),
             pygame.Rect(SCREENWIDTH-20,0,20,SCREENHEIGHT),pygame.Rect(0,SCREENHEIGHT-20,SCREENWIDTH,20)):
    risk = risks[random.randint(0,2)]
    GeoFence(rect, risk, all_sprites, fences)

# create influence zones for all geo-fences
for rect in (pygame.Rect(495,135,105,80), pygame.Rect(435,235,98,68), pygame.Rect(435,355,98,76)):
    GeoFenceInfluenceZone(rect, all_sprites, fences_infl_zones)

# and the background
Background(IMG_BACKGROUND, [0,0], all_sprites)

carryOn = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while carryOn:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            carryOn = False
            pygame.display.quit()
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    all_sprites.update(screen)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(20)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this quite easily, since you can pass a callback function to [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) which is used to calculate if two sprites are colliding.

Pygame offers already several collision detection strategies, and the one you're looking for is [`pygame.sprite.collide_rect_ratio`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect_ratio):

> A callable class that checks for collisions between two sprites, using a scaled version of the sprites rects.

---

Use it like this to get what you want:

```
def handle_risks(self):
    for s in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, fences, False, pygame.sprite.collide_rect_ratio(0.8)):
         ....
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I posted the image of the case of two workers and one fence. The collision between one of the workers and the fence is detected when indeed there is no collision.

Comment: @ScalaBoy That happens because you add the workers to the `fences`, `building_materials`  and `machines` groups, which you should propably not do. So if there are multiple workers in `fences`, an accident will happen when these workers collide.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand what you mean by adding workers to multiple groups. Probably I do not fully understand what happens when groups are created `workers = pygame.sprite.Group()`, etc. I understood it as the grouping of sprites of the same type into the same group. Therefore I do not get what you mean by adding workers to multiple groups.

Comment: @ScalaBoy You are correct about the grouping, but: look at this line: `Worker(IMG_WORKER_RUNNING, IMG_WORKER_IDLE, IMG_WORKER_ACCIDENT, pos, all_sprites, workers, building_materials, machines, fences)`. Here you pass all the groups to Worker's `__init__` function and hence each worker is added to all_sprites, workers, building_materials, machines and fences.